# read.csv resulted in more rows than really is there

Tags: r, rows, read.csv

when I am trying to read.csv [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RP1luOHImkCagXi38pxr0GiJpSkVnxtJ) dataset  in r there output has more rows than the actual dataset rows:

```
setwd("D:/yelp_dataset")
data1=read.csv("star3650000c.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE,fill=TRUE,quote=" 
",na.strings=c("NA","?"),dec=".",comment.char=" 
",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

what should i do?

Comment: What characteristics do the new rows have? One instance I can think is that you have a lot of NA rows at the bottom of your data. Sometimes in excel when you think you've deleted rows, it really just replaces with empties. I would test this by copying out the data you want from the file in to a new one and repeating your code. Or alternatively open with a text editor to see what excel isn't showing you. Try `tail(data1, 10)` to get last 10 rows. If you know the difference in rows, say `D`, try `tail(data1, D+1)`

Comment: `data1=read.csv("star3650000c.csv",sep=",",header=F,fill=F,na.strings=c("NA","?"),dec=".",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the main issue why reading the table does not work is that your definition of quoting and comment characters include line breaks (at least concerning the things you can control, if your data is corrupted you are usually lost). You might specify them to reasonable values as shown below. Note that I have set `header = FALSE` to make it easier to check the final output.

```
character_with_line_break = " 
"
# note that the line break is actually included in your character as "\n"
character_with_line_break
# [1] " \n"
# try read with different values for quote and comment characters
df =  read.csv("yelp.csv"
               ,sep=","
               ,header=FALSE
               ,fill=TRUE
                ,quote = "\""
                ,na.strings=c("NA","?")
                ,dec=".",comment.char=""
               ,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# there is still something wrong with the last line, 
# would have to investigate this further (probably missing EOL marker)
# but the final output looks good (see further down)
# Warning message:
#   In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
#                   incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'yelp.csv'
dim(df)
# [1]  4 10
data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) substr(x, 1, 10)))
# V1         V2 V3       V4 V5         V6 V7         V8 V9        V10
# 1  0 uQJ5RNygSe  2 8/4/2011  1 afEfPToTLj  5 I took my   2 uiZMpQSqJ4
# 2  1 VcGyezSNtk  4 1/4/2011  1 lGLLA08Ql4  5 Delicious!  5 uiZMpQSqJ4
# 3  2 39YKi45Pet  1 8/9/2013  0     #NAME?  5 After many  1 uiZMpQSqJ4
# 4  3 UTTTKI61dC  4 3/9/2012  1 Ly5ky2bAoJ  5 Love this  10 uiZMpQSqJ4
```

Comment: I have edited link for the dataset to entire of them

Comment: I have downloaded your file and just changed the filename in my code to "starc3650000.csv". This gives me a data.frame with `dim(df)
# [1] 50002    15`. Is this correct for your data set?

Comment: glad i could help, if you feel that my answer is worth it please consider upvoting and/or accepting it.